# TFS Rest API : Operation Timed out

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to get project collection using TFS REST API as follows,

```
curl -u "username@domain.com"[:"personal access token"] 
https://tfstracker.visualstudio.com:8080/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?
api-version=2.0
```

It fails with following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to tfstracker.visualstudio.com port 8080: Operation timed out.
```

I am using TFS online, i.e. web version.

UPDATE1:

Tried calling the API as suggested but got following error:

```
curl -u <username>[:<AccessToken>] https://tfstracker.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=tfstracker.visualstudio.com&amp;reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftfstracker.visualstudio.com%2FDefaultCollection%2F_apis%2Fprojects%3Fapi-version%3D1.0&amp;redirect=1&amp;context=eyJodCI6MiwiaGlkIjoiOGE4OWMxODUtNDRjNC00YWRkLWI3ZjgtZWIyNDhiZTIwMjAyIiwicXMiOnt9LCJyciI6IiIsInZoIjoiIiwiY3YiOiIiLCJjcyI6IiJ90#ctx=eyJTaWduSW5Db29raWVEb21haW5zIjpbImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbSIsImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbSJdfQ2">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

UPDATE2:
Here is the command that works

```
curl -u "username@domain.com:accesstoken" https://tfstracker.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0
```

Comment: Are you using on-premise TFS or VSTS? Do you want to get a team project or a project collection?

Comment: I am using TFS online, team project or Project collection - Anything will do.  In POC stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use VSTS, the URL should be like `https://tfstracker.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`, no port.

If you use on-premise TFS, the URL should be like `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`.

According to your API, it seems you want to get a list of team projects, not a project collection. The API to [get a list of team projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects) is as below:

```
Get http(s)://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0
```

If you want to [get a project collection](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/project-collections), the API should look like:

```
GET http(s)://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/projectCollections/{collection}?api-version=1.0-preview.2
```

> instance: VS Team Services account ({account}.visualstudio.com) or TFS
>   server ({server:port}).

---

**Update:**

I've tested the following command, and it works. Correct your format and make sure you have followed [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview) to create a personal access token.

> curl -u "*username@domain.com*:*personal access token*"
>   https://tfstracker.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0

Comment: I tried following 

 curl -u <username>[:<accesstoke>] https://tfstracker.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0

I got following result:

<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=tfstracker.visualstudio.com&amp;....SNIP

Comment: Sure. I have added it to main question.

Comment: You are right syntax is incorrect, thanks for your help.